# SocialEngine(Zend) returns error when instantiating a model of table

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, module, socialengine

When I want to instantiate a model from a table with this code below:

**Articlemanagement/Model/DbTable/Articles.php:**

```
class Articlemanagement_Model_DbTable_Articles extends Engine_Db_Table
{
    protected $_rowClass = 'Articlemanagement_Model_Article';
}
```

**Articlemanagement/Model/Article.php:**

```
class Articlemanagement_Model_Article extends Core_Model_Item_Abstract
{
    protected $_owner_type = 'user';
}
```

**Articlemanagement/controllers/AdminIndexController.php:**

```
class Articlemanagement_AdminIndexController extends Core_Controller_Action_Admin
{
  public function indexAction()
  {      
      $table = Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('articles', 'articlemanagement');
  }
}
```

it returns this error below:
exception 'Engine_Loader_Exception' with message 'Could not load class: Articlemanagement_Model_DbTable_Articles' in public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Loader.php:131

How can I fix it?

Comment: Mst be some spelling mistake. Recheck your code.

Answer (score 0):

Must be some spelling mistake. Recheck your code